# Application of Intermediate Value T.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the set of real numbers. If
$f(x)f(1-x)<0$ for each $x\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, then find $f(\frac{1}{2})$.

I guess we obtain $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$ by applying the intermediate value theorem. However, I am unable to implement it. Help pls.

Answer (score 5):

No need for  IVT.

Let $x \to \frac   12$ to get  $f(\frac  1 2)f(\frac 1  2) \leq 0$. This implies $f(\frac 1  2)=0$. [$a^{2}\ge 0$ for every real number $a$].